# SpriteKit without the gamescene.sks file

Tags: ios

A SpriteKit query: please can someone help? I cannot see why my gamescene.swift is not being presented.

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var newview = SKView()
        view.addSubview(newview)
        let  gamescene = GameScene(size: CGSize(width: view.bounds.width, height: view.bounds.height))

    newview.frame = self.view.frame
       // Present the scene
        newview.presentScene(gamescene)
    }
}
```

The gamescene is just

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    self.backgroundColor = .green
    let sprite = SKSpriteNode(color: .red, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
    sprite.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
    addChild(sprite)
        }
```

}

Comment: ..but what if you try to set the frame for your skview.. like: `newview.frame = self.view.frame` ?

Comment: Thanks Tony - that certainly rendered the background but there still seems to be a problem. When I add a spritenode it does not get rendered! (See edited code.)

Comment: C'mon! Your spritenode need a position, too.... https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sknode/1483101-position

Comment: Thanks again Tony, but I'm afraid adding a position didn't help. Sorry to be so dense. I guess the original question I should have asked is: " is there a concise list somewhere of the data provided by a (possibly blank) gamescene.sks file that needs to be picked up if one is working programmatically?".

Comment: There is not a concise list... but you can inspire from here: https://www.appcoda.com/spritekit-introduction/

Comment: That's very helpful Tony - thanks once again.

Comment: Hi Just wondering if you really need to make a subview? Is this something you want to do or is it just code that works